# Sound Card to Circumvent Sound Problems?

Tags: sound, soundcard, hda-intel

I have very choppy sound on my HP EliteDesk 800 G3 running Ubuntu 22.04.3 uses 6.2 kernel. I have tried many solutions and I give up ... but if I put in a sound card, for example the Creative Sound Blaster Audigy Fx V2, would that completely circumvent the onboard sound chip? If drivers are my problem with the current sound card HDA Intel, would getting a different sound card solve the problem? Correct me if I am wrong, my understanding is that drivers are not a problem for most newer sound cards with Ubuntu. Thank you.

Update: I tried booting several other distros of Ubuntu (14.04.6, 16.04.7, 18.04.6, 20.04.6). I don't know why but the only one that would boot was 20.04.6. For the others Bios said "could not validate" or something like that. I have since realized (and please correct me if I am wrong) I should have manually tried different kernels in each distro. I did not realize that was a thing. I only used the default kernel in those two installations. Sound was a problem for both. I returned that refurbished machine because it had other problems, maybe damage in shipping, the case was damaged. So, now any further comments are pedagogical. Thanks for the previous comments. I am learning a lot and I am inspired to go about learning in a more systematic way.

Comment: Its Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Please add that detail to your question; this is a Q&A site and not a forum, answers will be to your question, comments are intended for *comments about the question itself*, and get removed once addressed in the question.  FYI:  All 22.04 Desktop media default to HWE, so you'll only have GA kernel stack if you installed on an earlier release & *release-upgraded* to 22.04, or switched kernel stack options yourself.  Details do matter, so if upgraded to 22.04.3 please be specific, or you can just state your kernel stack (22.04.3 uses 5.15 kernel if using GA, & 6.2 if using HWE)

Comment: Comment on "*drivers are not a problem*"...  I'm involved in QA and find kernel stack really matters, esp. on newer hardware (you want the latest) & older hardware (older stacks can work better). The easiest way to check is using *live* media; eg. 5 kernels are/were available for 20.04 desktop media (5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15), with 3 available for 22.04 (5.15, 5.19 & 6.2) thus I'd use *live* media to explore that (nothing needs be installed) though multiple stacks can co-exist unless using some closed-source kernel modules (some nvidia). *live* testing would also confirm not config issue.

Comment: My guess from your additional details is you have *Secure boot* on, and are using uEFI, as that would explain your inability to boot older ISOs than [20.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) where link will give clue on second paragraph (and what I suspect caused error message; being your machine's *firmware* message for revoked key). If it was me, I'd want likely  have tried *live* older 22.04 ISO (.1 especially using 5.15 kernel as its still supported; https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/) though it may fail to boot as it too uses *revoked* key

Comment: To get older ISOs to boot, you may need to go into *firmware* settings (hit ESC on boot, and its F10 on the hp.elitedesk.400 I had within reach) & change "*Secure Boot*" to disabled. I'd also re-test sound with your machine booted like this normally too (*you may get lucky as some hardware is less 'strict/fussy' with it disabled*).   If your *Secure Boot* is already *disabled*, then I'm missing something sorry.